# JDBC connect with password but no username?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a server (via JDBC) which requires a password, but a blank username.  When I try using an empty String ("") it causes an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call

The code I am using worked to connect to another server (which requires username and password), so it is operable; just not in this specific case (empty string username).  I also can access the connection for this specific server which requires no username via SQLDeveloper, so that's not offline or inaccessible.  In SQLDeveloper I can enter an empty username field without incident.

From what I've read one can connect with JDBC with username and password, or with neither.  But I can't find a solution for a blank username.  There must be a hacky way around the problem.

```
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
    ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid);
    System.out.println("attempting connection");
    connection = ds.getConnection(textFieldUsername.getText(), new String(passwordField.getPassword()));
    System.out.println("connection established");
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Have u tried this  connection = ds.getConnection(null, new String(passwordField.getPassword()));

Comment: how should server determine which user's password should be verified in your case?

Comment: @PankajSaboo Yes, and just tried it again to be sure.  Same error.  
"java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call"

Comment: @RafaelOsipov connection is to a server which uses connections shared by a group for access; in which case it doesn't seem to verify much, and username/password details are shared amongst the relevant developers.

Comment: "The code I am using worked to connect to another server" - also with no username? Then compare the user/security setting of the two servers I would say.

Comment: @Fildor oh, sorry for ambiguity (will edit), no, with username and password.

Comment: I have never heard of a database server that doesn't require a username as well as a password.

Comment: @EJP I presume there's some sort of authentication going on in the background, but in this case the connection requires a blank username.  Surely you've encountered something like that before?

Comment: Is that some custom rolled authentication thingy? Maybe you could get it to accept a (dummy?) username instead of trying to abuse JDBC to use an empty username.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk When I first tried to connect to this server using the no username and password it failed because I hadn't access, obviously it's automatically authenticated somehow.  Problem is, if I enter any username instead of none, it throws "invalid username/password; logon denied" at me.  I can connect to server using this connection in SQLDeveloper; from which I can leave username field blank, so it's not like it's inaccessible or offline.  Any thoughts?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Oracle will never allow you to login with a blank username. Are you using OS authentication from SQL Developer to authenticate against the database?

Comment: Not that I have done, it must be OS level in the background.  As stated initially, I could connect using this code to another related server, which required username and password, without purposefully or knowingly authenticating my individual username or password.  The username/password for server connections my code is using is not my individual work login, just a login for any dev using the server.  The server knew somehow that this connection accessed via JDBC to execute SQL queries was legal because my work login is safe?  I am very confused!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect through the DriverManager interface?

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);`

Where `props` doesn't have any entry for the username.